# Testing a webapi controller using "Moq"

Tags: c#, owin

I'm learning about unit tests using Moq, and I have a very simple Webapi Controller that only returns status OK.

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/v1/test")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetHealth()
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Well I don't know how to test it using Moq, I will appreciate some help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

No need for **Moq** I think.

In your unit test you can instantiate a new controller.

```
var testController = new TestController();
```

With this you can then call the methods.

```
[Test]
public void TestHealth(){
  var testController = new TestController();
  var result = testController.GetHealth() as HttpResponseMessage
  Assert.That(result, Is.Not.Null);
  Assert.That(result.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(200));
}
```

Comment: If you're actually testing the logic of the controller itself, you wouldn't want to mock it anyway!  Good spot!

Answer (score 0):

Typically I do not test the Web API level of my controllers and focus on the business logic for mocking and / or integration testing of my code. I don't like to say that you shouldn't test controllers if they contain some logic that needs tested, it's just something that I do not test when building a solution. If my controllers contain logic that need testing I try to abstract what I can into another layer. However, it looks like the Microsoft documentation actually uses the Moq code to test the controller classes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api